# Linux MTU and UDP

Tags: linux, mtu

Can someone please explain this behavior to me?  I have a few VMS (centos) running on a cloud provider.  The interface is set to the standard 1500 MTU.

pinging with large ICMP packets works fine:

```
# ping -s 1600 10.132.6.3
PING 10.132.6.3 (10.132.6.3) 1600(1628) bytes of data.
1608 bytes from 10.132.6.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.16 ms
1608 bytes from 10.132.6.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.09 ms
1608 bytes from 10.132.6.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
^C
--- 10.132.6.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2207ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.044/1.101/1.168/0.063 ms
```

So it seems something is fragmenting the ICMP traffic.

But large UDP traffic does not make it:

```
]# nping --udp -p 111 -data-length 1600 10.132.6.3
WARNING: Payload exceeds maximum recommended payload (1400)

Starting Nping 0.5.51 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2015-08-10 18:06 EDT
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(3, packet, 1628, 0, 10.132.40.29, 16)   => Message too long
Offending packet: UDP 10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499   iplen=1628
SENT (0.0082s) UDP 10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499 iplen=1628
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(3, packet, 1628, 0, 10.132.40.29, 16) => Message too long
Offending packet: UDP 10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499  iplen=1628
SENT (1.0086s) UDP10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499  iplen=1628
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(3, packet, 1628, 0, 10.132.40.29, 16) => Message too long
Offending packet: UDP 10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499 iplen=1628
SENT (2.0097s) UDP 10.132.6.3:53 > 10.132.40.29:111 ttl=64 id=17499 iplen=1628

Max rtt: N/A | Min rtt: N/A | Avg rtt: N/A
Raw packets sent: 3 (4.884KB) | Rcvd: 0 (0B) | Lost: 3 (100.00%)
Tx time: 2.34513s | Tx bytes/s: 2082.61 | Tx pkts/s: 1.28
Rx time: 2.34513s | Rx bytes/s: 0.00 | Rx pkts/s: 0.00
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 2.35 seconds
```

Any thoughts as to why the UDP traffic is not being fragmented?

Answer (score 2):

The `sendto` error is coming from `nping`, which is receiving it back from the OS socket library (i.e., locally - not from somewhere on the network).  Seems that `nping` is just trying to send 1600 byte UDP packets, but the OS can't send them.

OTOH, if you use the `--mtu` option to `nping`, it will fragment the packets.  It's apparently not counting the IP header in its MTU, because the largest I can set the MTU is 1480.

```
nping --udp -p 111 -data-length 1600 --mtu 1480 some-host
WARNING: Payload exceeds maximum recommended payload (1400)

Starting Nping 0.5.51 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2015-08-11 10:29 EDT
SENT (0.0056s) UDP 192.168.1.40:53 > 192.168.1.14:111 ttl=64 id=58221 iplen=1628
RCVD (0.0068s) ICMP 192.168.1.14 > 192.168.1.40 Destination host 192.168.1.14 administratively prohibited (type=3/code=10) ttl=64 id=33478 iplen=576
```

Meanwhile, regular old `ping` must be automatically fragmenting the packets before giving them to the OS.

A good technique for investigating this sort of thing is to use `tcpdump` to sniff what is actually happening on the network.

```
tcpdump -s0 -w /tmp/tcpdump.out host 192.168.1.1
```

you can then download tcpdump.out and inspect its contents with wireshark.

if you omit -s0 it will only capture the first 64 (i think) bytes of each packet. For this case that would be plenty.